# Pull data without loop

Tags: java

I have this code which I want to use to verify file processing from database status table:

```
package com.file.verifier;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Application extends SqlUtils {

    private static String folderPath = "D:\\EntityImportEversana";

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Running file verifier");
        System.out.println("monitoring folder " + folderPath);
        SqlUtils sql = new SqlUtils();

        WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        Path path = Paths.get(folderPath);
        path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
        WatchKey key;
        while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                System.out.println("Event kind:" + event.kind() + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ".");
                if(event.kind().equals(StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE)){
                    Instant start = Instant.now();

                    boolean flag = true;

                        while(flag) {
                            while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
                                HashMap<String, List> map = sql.checkFileImport();

                                List values = map.get(event.context()); // get values by file name
                                if(values.contains("Completed")){
                                    // exit the monitoring while loop
                                    flag = false;
                                }
                            }
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }

                    Instant end = Instant.now();
                    System.out.println(Duration.between(start,end));

                    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(Duration.between(start,end).getSeconds());
                    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(Duration.between(start,end).getSeconds());

                    System.out.format("Execution time %d minutes %d seconds", minutes, seconds);


                }

            }
            key.reset();
        }

        watchService.close();
    }
}
```

SQL requests file:

```
package com.file.verifier;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.*;

public class SqlUtils {

    String connectionUrl =
            "jdbc:sqlserver://......";

    protected HashMap<String, List> checkFileImport(){
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        HashMap<String, List> map = new HashMap<>();

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
             Statement statement = connection.createStatement();) {

            // Create and execute a SELECT SQL statement.
            String selectSql = "SELECT * from integration.EntityImportRequests";
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSql);

            // Print results from select statement
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                map.put(resultSet.getString(3), Arrays.asList(resultSet.getString(5),
                                                                         resultSet.getString(6),
                                                                         resultSet.getString(7)));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

I use this code to detect the file import. How I can replace the while loop with something better? When there is a error status I would like to stop the execution and print and print the processing error.

Comment: *"How I can replace the while loop with something better?"* - if by saying "something better" you imply a Stream, then it's not possible to do (in a way that is clean, well-readable). Since you need to dial with handling `SQLException` at every interaction with the `ResultSet` (while moving the cursor and while extracting values).

Comment: The same with `WatchService`. By the way, it wouldn't be closed in case of Exception.